# How would one translate "pick up lines"?

Tags: expressões, gíria, tradução, frases

In English, there's the phrase *pick up line*. It stands for a sentence or group of sentences (usually not more than a few, definitely less than a paragraph) that indicate an attempt at one person to "pick up", or attract attention from, someone of the opposite sex.

Some samples of pick up lines in English are:

- Did it hurt? When you fell from heaven?
- Hey baby, I wish you were asynchronous, so you'd give me a callback.
- Guess what I'm wearing? The smile you gave me.
- Know what's on the menu? Me 'n U.

I know (or suspect) that similar "lines" exist in Portuguese, but what are they *called*? **Linha de levantar** doesn't seem like it fits.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Brazilian Portuguese, the best translation would be the substantive "[cantada](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/escolar/ingles/definicao/portugues-ingles/cantada_16511.html)":

> *sf bras, coloq** seduction and a proposition. **dar/passar uma cantada em** to make a pass at someone, to chat someone up.

But I should add that there are some other completely different meanings for the word "cantada" (specially as an adjective or verb instead of a substantive).

And, as stated by bfavaretto in a comment, the word "[xaveco](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/xaveco/)" probably also fits.

However, in my personal opinion, "cantada" fits better than "xaveco" because for me "xaveco" seems to be a bit (but only a bit) too broad for this because it could also fits sometimes (but surely not always) as a synonym for "[paquera](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/paquera/)". And "paquera", although related, is clearly not the same thing as "cantada".

* <sup><sub>"sf bras, coloq" means feminine substantive, Brazilian, coloquial</sub></sup>

Answer (score 7):

In European Portuguese, a possible translation is [frase de engate](http://context.reverso.net/traducao/portugues-ingles/frase+de+engate).

Comment: Também pode ser _linha de engate_.

Answer (score 6):

Also in European Portuguese, we have the informal word [*piropo*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/piropo).

> substantivo masculino
>
> [Portugal, Informal]  Expressão ou frase dirigida a alguém, geralmente para demonstrar apreciação física (ex.: ficou corado com o piropo; piropo de mau gosto).